# Is it necessary to create FactX and DimX tables manually for MS BI Analysis Services?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, olap

I have an OLTP database. For this database, I want to use SQL 2008 R2 Analysis Services. So I created a new project in Visual Studio using the BI template 'Analysis Services Project'.

Do I need to create FactXXX and DimXXX tables manually on the server, or is it somehow possible to do this in Visual Studio?

For instance, can Dimension Wizard (Right click on "Dimensions" folder in solution explorer -> New Dimension -> Use Existing table) be used for the dimensions, or is it for some other purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you create denormalized fact and dimension tables that you then use as a data source for your SSAS project.

Reasons for creating these denormalized tables include performance (faster processing of cubes/dimensions and taking load off the OLTP database) and cleanliness (fact and dimension tables are clearly defined).

You don't *have* to use physical tables, though. You can create views that provide the same information, or define the queries right in the data source view (using named queries).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there a guided way (e.g. a wizard or a tool) of creating the denormalized tables? Also, if I don't use physical tables, would that affect performance badly?

Comment: No, you must create them manually. The performance penalty depends on your data and database usage, but it's definitely slower.